# BigQuery, SQL : Last full n months

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I copy my query from PostgreSQL to BigQuery.
In PostgreSQL, I have used this syntax to get dates from 4 full months from today:

```
WHERE date>= date_trunc('month', current_date-interval '4 months')
```

this return full 4 months from today so if today 10/02/2021 I get dates from 01/10/2020-10/02/2021
Now I try to get the same result in BQ with:

```
WHERE DATE(date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

But this return only 4 months from today 10/10/2020-10/02/2021

How can I fix the query to get a full 4 months?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To truncate dates in BigQuery use [DATE_TRUNC](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_trunc):

```
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_TRUNC(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 4 MONTH), MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```